# How to retrieve the id of an inserted row in ZF2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am creating a message system in ZF2.

I have a **threads** table:

```
id             INT primary key auto_increment
title          TEXT
```

And a **messages** table:

```
message_id     INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
thread_id      INT foreign key references threads.id
message        TEXT
```

(Rows and other referenced tables were left out which are not entirely pertinent to this question.)

In my MessageTable model, it keeps an instance of the ThreadTable. When MessageTable::saveMessage( Message $message ) is called it creates a Thread model and in turn calls ThreadTable::saveThread( Thread $thread ).

Since my Message model requires the thread_id, it needs to know the threads.id we just inserted before I can insert the new message.

I do not know how to retrieve the id that we just inserted. How would I get the last inserted id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = $adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();
```

Comment: Ah that was embarrassingly easy. (And should have probably showed up in my search results!) Thank you very much.